# I want to save all the errors in a log file that I will get from a migration script in flyway, is there any way I can do that?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

Can anyone tell me way where I can get all the errors from a migration script in **flyway** into a log file or some other type of file in a single run.

I don't want to fix the error in the migration script then check for the statements below it if they will throw error or not.

database I am using is postgres

previously I was trying to handle the errors from a shell script that I have written but as soon as there is a error in the migration script it saves the error in a file and don't check or execute the statements below it if they will give an error or not

Comment: Hello, is this script running in a test environment? I am trying to figure out if you want the migration to continue running when it hits an error so you can figure out all of the errors in that migration in one run?